# select multiple count set, sql server 2008 r2

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Using SQL Server 2008 R2, i have following result set returned by a query -

```
QID    QcID    QtID    QsID
21      1       SC      3
4       1       SC      1
8       1       MC      1
2       1       SC      1
23      1       SC      3
24      1       SC      3
5       1       SC      1
22      1       SC      3
1       1       SC      1
29      1       MC      3
10      1       MC      1
30      1       MC      3
26      1       MC      3
25      1       SC      3
6       1       MC      1
27      1       MC      3
7       1       MC      1
3       1       SC      1
28      1       MC      3
9       1       MC      1
```

Now i want to find a random set of 15 QID, which must includes say -

```
 9 QsID having QsID = 1
 6 QsID having QsID = 3
 9 QtID having QtID = SC
 6 QtID having QtID = MC
 15 QsID having QtID = 1
```

how it can be done keeping performance in mind as it may have tens of thousand records.

@ Damien_The_Unbeliever the expected output could be -

```
21      1       SC       3
4       1       SC       1
8       1       MC       1
2       1       SC       1
23      1       SC       3
24      1       SC       3
5       1       SC       1
1       1       SC       1
10      1       MC       1
25      1       SC       3
6       1       MC       1
27      1       MC       3
7       1       MC       1
3       1       SC       1
28      1       MC       3
```

Also forget the random, how it be possible to select the set satisfying all the conditions.

Comment: i was thinking to implement multiple having clause, but i am confuse how to use them in this situation

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your criteria (aren't 5 & 6 the same as 1 & 2?) If the "random" 15 have to meet all of the criteria, are you sure that 15 rows will even match them? Can you give your expected output(s) from the sample data you've provided?

Comment: yea sorry, that was a typo so i have edited the question, is it clear to you now?

Comment: well what i want to select a set of QID from the above which must include say x% of QcID and y% of QtID and z% of QsID

Comment: Does the x, y, z % has to be same? or differ? or it doesn't matter as long as there's some from c, t, s IDs?

Comment: x,y,z are predefined variable percentage, most likely the will be different like 20,30,40% etc.

Comment: So in each % for each QID, you need c, t, s ID to be unique?

Comment: QID for the final set of 15 Question must be unique

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT2:**

Well, how about using a stored procedure for that?
Assumption is that you have 4 sets of conditions you sample data with. Deduced from the output you provided. It might not be right but then again you can adjust it as you like.

Parameters:

- `@SIZE` - is the size of sampling result set in rows
- `@P1-@P3` - percent of the sampling result set that should be filled with random rows for particular set of conditions.
- `@P4=@SIZE-(@N1+@N2+@N3)`

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE sqlsampling 
    @SIZE INT, @P1 DECIMAL(6,4), @P2 DECIMAL(6,4), @P3 DECIMAL(6,4) 
AS 

DECLARE @N1 INT, @N2 INT, @N3 INT, @N4 INT;
SET @N1=CEILING(@SIZE*@P1*0.01);
SET @N2=CEILING(@SIZE*@P2*0.01);
SET @N3=CEILING(@SIZE*@P3*0.01);
SET @N4=@SIZE-(@N1+@N2+@N3);

CREATE TABLE #sample(QID INT, QcID INT, QtID CHAR(2), QsID INT);

INSERT INTO #sample 
SELECT TOP(@N1) * FROM mytable 
WHERE QtID = 'MC' AND QsID = 1 
ORDER BY CHECKSUM(NEWID());

INSERT INTO #sample 
SELECT TOP(@N2) * FROM mytable 
WHERE QtID = 'MC' AND QsID = 3 AND QID NOT IN(SELECT QID FROM #sample)
ORDER BY CHECKSUM(NEWID());

INSERT INTO #sample 
SELECT TOP(@N3) * FROM mytable 
WHERE QtID = 'SC' AND QsID = 1 AND QID NOT IN(SELECT QID FROM #sample)
ORDER BY CHECKSUM(NEWID()); 

INSERT INTO #sample
SELECT TOP(@N4) * FROM mytable 
WHERE QtID = 'SC' AND QsID = 3 AND QID NOT IN(SELECT QID FROM #sample)
ORDER BY CHECKSUM(NEWID());

SELECT * FROM #sample;
DROP TABLE #sample;
GO
```

If we execute it on your sample data like this

```
EXEC sqlsampling @SIZE=15, @P1=26.666, @P2=13.333, @P3=33.333;
```

It will give us the output:

```
QID QCID QTID QSID
10  1    MC   1
9   1    MC   1
7   1    MC   1
6   1    MC   1
27  1    MC   3
30  1    MC   3
1   1    SC   1
4   1    SC   1
3   1    SC   1
5   1    SC   1
2   1    SC   1
21  1    SC   3
23  1    SC   3
25  1    SC   3
24  1    SC   3
```

Other considerations:

- Correct indexes for your sets of conditions should help
- `CHECKSUM(NEWID())` helps us a bit with the penalty of using `NEWID()`

**Original answer:**

You can do something like this:

```
SELECT TOP 15 * FROM
(
SELECT * FROM (SELECT TOP 9 QID FROM mytable 
WHERE QsID = 1 
ORDER BY CHECKSUM(NEWID())) a
 UNION
SELECT * FROM (SELECT TOP 6 QID FROM mytable 
WHERE QsID = 3 
ORDER BY CHECKSUM(NEWID())) b
...
) z ORDER BY CHECKSUM(NEWID())
```

Comment: well this give me more then 15 records, and newid is not good for performance wise, what do you think ?

Comment: Updated the answer. That will give you 15 if you can live with `NEWID()`

Comment: using CHECKSUM(NEWID()) might speed things up a little when ordering

Comment: well i think this may not follow all the condition as at the end you are selecting top 15 randomly ?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you may try `percent` with `top`.. this is not the complete answer, but to throw some light into the direction..

```
select  * from demo where qid in 
(select top 40 percent qid
 from demo order by newid())
;
```

Here is also a Reference to `tablesample`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189108.aspx